# React + Formik: Use value for nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

I have the following model for my React (TypeScript) app:

```js
interface IProjectInput {
    id?: string;
    name: string | i18n;
    description: string | i18n;
}
```

```js
export interface i18n {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

I am using `Formik` and `react-bootstrap` to create a new `ProjectInput` from a `Form`:

```js
import { i18n as I18n, ... } from 'my-models';

interface State {
    validated: boolean;
    project: IProjectInput;
}

/**
 * A Form that can can edit a project
 */
class ProjectForm extends Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            project: props.project || {
                name: {},
                description: ''
            },
            validated: false
        };
    }

    async handleSubmit(values: FormikValues, actions: FormikHelpers<IProjectInput>) {
        let project = new ProjectInput();
        project = { ...project, ...values };
        console.log("form values", values);
        // actions.setSubmitting(true);
        // try {
        //     await this.props.onSubmit(project);
        // } catch (e) { }
        // actions.setSubmitting(false);
    }

    render() {
        const { t } = this.props;
        const getCurrentLng = () => i18n.language || window.localStorage.i18nextLng || '';
        const init = this.state.project || {
            name: {},
            description: ''
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <Formik
                    // validationSchema={ProjectInputSchema}
                    enableReinitialize={false}
                    onSubmit={(values, actions) => this.handleSubmit(values, actions)}
                    initialValues={init}
                >
                    {({
                        handleSubmit,
                        handleChange,
                        handleBlur,
                        values,
                        touched,
                        errors,
                        isSubmitting,
                        setFieldTouched
                    }) => {

                        return (
                            <div className="project-form">
                                <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Group as={Col} md={{span: 5}} controlId="projectName">
                                            <Form.Label>
                                                {t('projectName')}
                                            </Form.Label>
                                            // Input for ENGLISH text
                                            <Form.Control
                                                type="text"
                                                name="name"
                                                value={(values['name'] as I18n).en}
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                            />
                                            // Input for FRENCH text
                                            <Form.Control
                                                type="text"
                                                name="name"
                                                value={(values['name'] as I18n).fr}
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                            />
                                        </Form.Group>
```

So in the end it should look like:

```
{
  "name": {
    "en": "yes",
    "fr": "oui"
  },
  "description" : "test",
  ...
}
```

My problem is, that the value for the `name` input stays empty.

I tried to add `const init = this.state.project || { name: { 'en': '' },` in my `render` or for my `state`, but this did not do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

Change in your `Form.Control` the prop `name` to `name.en`/`name.fr`

---

First of all, `initialValues` is a prop that will be set and won't change unless you pass the prop `enableReinitialize`. So it isn't good to do `this.state.project || { name: { 'en': '' }` because it will only assume the first value of that, it can be `this.state.project` or `{ name: { 'en': '' }`, but you will never know.

Second, to solve your problem, if you look at the docs about [`handleChange`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeevent-any-void):

> General input change event handler. This will update the `values[key]` where key is the event-emitting input's `name` attribute. If the `name` attribute is not present, `handleChange` will look for an input's `id` attribute. Note: "input" here means all HTML inputs.

But in your `Form.Control` you are passing the `name` attribute as `name="name"`.

So it's trying to update `name` and not e.g. `name.en`.

You should change

```
   <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={(values['name'] as I18n).en}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
    // Input for FRENCH text
    <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={(values['name'] as I18n).fr}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

To

```
   <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="name.en" // correct name
        value={(values['name'] as I18n).en}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
    // Input for FRENCH text
    <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="name.fr" // correct name
        value={(values['name'] as I18n).fr}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

Here is the [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/arrays#nested-objects) that shows why you should use `name.en` instead of just `name`.

Comment: Sometimes I feel really dumb, like right now... THANK YOU @Vencovsky for taking your time and not only posting the correct answer but also a really good explanation! I read this document page but totally overlooked the `name`part.

Comment: My last question for today will be, how I could declare `name: {}` to avoid getting `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled.` I could do `name: {'en':'','fr':''}` everywhere but I do not want to hardcode it :) @Vencovsky

Comment: @mrks you need to hard code it. If the input on the page is hard coded, then you need to hard code it. If the input is conditionally rendered or rendered by `.map` and things like that, you should do the same in the `name: {}`. To avoid `changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled` the `input`  name rendered must be in the `initialValues`.

Answer (score 1):

It described in docs https://formik.org/docs/guides/arrays

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';

export const NestedExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Social Profiles</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        social: {
          facebook: '',
          twitter: '',
        },
      }}
      onSubmit={values => {
        // same shape as initial values
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <Field name="social.facebook" />
        <Field name="social.twitter" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  </div>
);
```